Why is my CCD IK algorithm not properly axis locking the joints?
I'm attempting to implement Quaternion Cyclic Coordinate Descent Inverse Kinematics in python based on this guide.
So far I've had success with a simple bone chain, but I'm stuck on implementing the axis lock to limit each joint to hinge motion.
Below is my code:
MAX_CCD_ITERATIONS = 10
CCD_THRESHOLD = 5 # millimetres

class Bone:
    def __init__(self, name, head, tail, parent=None, ik_axis=[0, 0, 0], ik_min_angle=-np.pi, ik_max_angle=np.pi):
        -- cut for brevity --
        self.rotation = R.identity()

    def get_head(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.get_tail() + self.head
        else:
            return self.head

    def get_tail(self):
        global_head = self.get_head()
        tail_vector = self.tail
        rotated_tail_vector = self.get_rotation().apply(tail_vector)
        return global_head + rotated_tail_vector

    def get_rotation(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return self.parent.get_rotation() * self.rotation
        else:
            return self.rotation

    def solve_ccd(self, target, iterations=MAX_CCD_ITERATIONS):
        target=np.array(target)
        chain = self.get_ancestry_chain(3)
        for _ in range(iterations):
            for bone in chain:
                end_effector = self.get_tail()

                e_i = end_effector - bone.get_head()
                t_i = target - bone.get_head()

                rotation_i = R.align_vectors(e_i, t_i)[0]
                bone.rotation *= rotation_i

                # Apply axis constraints
                if bone.ik_axis.any():
                    current_axis = rotation_i.apply(bone.ik_axis)
                    rotation_back = R.align_vectors(current_axis, bone.ik_axis)[0]
                    bone.rotation *= rotation_back

                if np.linalg.norm(target - self.get_tail()) < CCD_THRESHOLD:
                    print("Threshold met. Close enough :P")
                    return

    def get_ancestry_chain(self, n):
        """Gets a list of nodes going up the chain, up to a max length of n."""

I tried plotting the result iteratively in matplotlib, and the end effector eventually reaches the target (although it takes longer than with the # Apply axis constraints block removed), but the bones still seem to be rotating wherever they like.
note: bone.ik_axis will be something like [0, 1, 0] or [0, 0, 1]
